# Checking ip:port is open on remote host

Tags: python, sockets, paramiko, ssh-tunnel, telnetlib

I have a list of servers and ip:ports (external addressses) and i need to check if each server can connect to those addresses.

Looping through the file and trying to open an sshtunnel and doing connect as below

```py
tunnel=sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
                                    ssh_host=host,
                                    ssh_port=22,
                                    ssh_username=ssh_username, 
                                    ssh_pkey=privkey,
                                    remote_bind_address=(addr_ip, int(addr_port)),
                                    local_bind_address=('0.0.0.0', 10022)
                                    #,logger=sshtunnel.create_logger(loglevel=10)        
                                )     
tunnel.start()
# use socket
try:

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    res = s.connect(('localhost', 10022))
    print(res)
    #s.connect((addr_ip, int(addr_port)))
    s.close()
except socket.error as err:
    print('socket err:')
    print(err)
finally:
    s.close()

time.sleep(2)
tunnel.stop()
```

When i do this though, the response is always 0 (i.e. the sock can connect to the local bind) even if the remote is incorrect - however sshtunnelforwarder throws

```
ERROR   | Secsh channel 0 open FAILED: Network is unreachable: Connect failed
ERROR   | Could not establish connection from ('127.0.0.1', 10022) to remote side of the tunnel
```

How do I make my socket command check if the remote_bind_address is available?

I tried to do use telnetlib, but get a similar issue

the code is effectively the same with the socket block replaced with

```py
tn=telnetlib.Telnet()
tn.open('localhost',10022)
tn.close()
```

Im relatively new to all this, so still learning. If there is a better way to achieve what i need to do please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: My Alternative is to use paramiko.SSHclient and do a telnet with exec_command, but i would rather try and do it all with python rather than call commands on the server.

Answer (score 3):

Set the attribute [`skip_tunnel_checkup`](https://sshtunnel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder.skip_tunnel_checkup) to `False` to enable checking of the remote side availability (it's disabled by default for backwards compatibility):

```
tunnel.skip_tunnel_checkup = False
```

Adding this before starting the tunnel checks the remote side is up on start and throws an exception which can be handled.

Removed my socket code.

Comment: Great you managed to solve your issue! I just would like to ask you, could you add a piece of code which shows when and where the exception is being thrown, please? It's not very clear from the answer. It may be useful for other looking for similar solution.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried that, but there's the [`tunnel_is_up`](https://sshtunnel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder.tunnel_is_up) attribute of the SSH tunnel class, which according to the documentation:

> Describe whether or not the other side of the tunnel was reported to be up (and we must close it) or not (skip shutting down that tunnel)

Example of its content (it's a dictionary):

```
{('127.0.0.1', 55550): True,  # this tunnel is up
('127.0.0.1', 55551): False}  # this one isn't
```

So you shouldn't need to make an explicit connection yourself.

**Note:** you may need to set the attribute [`skip_tunnel_checkup`](https://sshtunnel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder.skip_tunnel_checkup) to `False` (which is `True` by default for backwards compatibility) first before setting up the tunnel, otherwise `tunnel_is_up` may always report `True`:

> When `skip_tunnel_checkup` is disabled or the local bind is a UNIX socket, the value will always be `True`

So the code may look like:

```
tunnel=sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
    # ...
)
tunnel.skip_tunnel_checkup = False
tunnel.start()

# tunnel.tunnel_is_up should be populated with actual tunnel status(es) now
```

In the code you posted, you're setting up a tunnel and then just opening a socket to the **local endpoint of the tunnel**, which is apparently open no matter what state the tunnel is in, so it always connects successfully.

Another approach would be to actually try to establish an SSH connection through the tunnel, but that's the `paramiko.SSHclient` alternative you're mentioning in a comment I guess.

Comment: @zkssyth Did it help you solve your issue? If yes, then accept my answer, please. It will help others to find the right answer and it also rewards me with for my effort a few reputation points.

Comment: Just to clarify the other side of the tunnel is a different server. I tried tunnel is up and got true - even when i tried a made up address.

Comment: @zkssyth I see, OK, thanks for the information! And yep, I understood you're trying to set up a tunnel to a remote machine.